# 10Gbit home network speed issues

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, 10gbit

I recently upgraded my home network to 10Gbit but I don't get this speed.

**tl;dr:**
Two devices have 10Gbit network adapters and between the two I get max 2Gbit speed.

My Windows-based laptop with Wi-Fi 5 gets around 30/60Mbps

Below is a summary of my network devices and how they are connected

**My ISP > Netgear R7800 router > Netgear 10-port/10G switch (GS110EMX) > (Windows desktop PC and Ubuntu Linux desktop server)**

Specs of the machines:

```
Desktop Windows PC:  
    3x SanDisk Ultra 960GB SATA 3 HDDs 
    ipolex 10Gb PCI Express Network Card for Intel X550-T1

Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 18.04):
    Crucial m500 240GB SSD (OS installed on it) 
    2x WD Red 3.5 6TB HDDs
    2x WD Red 3.5 3TB HDDs
    ipolex 10Gb PCI Express Network Card for Intel X550-T1

Laptop (Thinkpad x1 extreme): 
    2TB Samsung 970 EVO  
    Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
```

The desktop PC is connected to the Netgear 10Gb switch using a Cat 8 cable that's 2m long and the Ubuntu server desktop is also connected to the same switch using a Cat 8 cable.

A single Cat 5e cable is used to connect the switch to the Netgear router that handles DHCP for all my network attached devices.

When I transfer some files located on one of my SanDisk SSDs and transfer it into my Ubuntu server I get only between 1-2Gbps.

- Is this due to an HDD bottleneck on the Windows PC or in the Ubuntu server?
- Would I only get the full 10Gbit speed if I had an m.2 NVME SSD attached to both the Windows PC and Ubuntu server?
- Does this data transfer go through my Netgear router and then back onto the switch, and might that cause the delay?
- Wi-Fi speed is also slow even when the laptop is right next to the router and has a Wi-Fi 5 card that should be capable of 1Gbit speeds.

iperf results below from desktop Windows to Ubuntu server

```
  Accepted connection from 192.168.1.18, port 63892
[  5] local 192.168.1.222 port 5201 connected to 192.168.1.18 port 63893
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   179 MBytes  1.50 Gbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   176 MBytes  1.47 Gbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   210 MBytes  1.76 Gbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   189 MBytes  1.59 Gbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   208 MBytes  1.74 Gbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   226 MBytes  1.90 Gbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   225 MBytes  1.89 Gbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   197 MBytes  1.65 Gbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   223 MBytes  1.87 Gbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   255 MBytes  2.14 Gbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-10.04  sec  6.14 MBytes  1.37 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 Gbits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  2.04 GBytes  1.75 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Have you tried transfers that do not involve disk storage? Like `iperf3`?

Comment: How do i use iperf3? do u have an example on how i can use it?

Comment: Download the GUI, it's easier to use. Search for jperf. You will need the Java runtime environment to run it.

Comment: Also, what version is the firmware running on the switch? Have you looked in the manual & switch admin page for flow control? I don't think this switch is going to give you the maximum throughput, but it definitely shouldn't be this slow...

Comment: I have just updated my post with iperf results

Comment: firmware version of switch is  1.0.0.2